# Angular Mat-select formcontrol select default value graphic

Tags: javascript, angular, angular10

I have a form Control in angular 10 form Group/ Form Array, i want edit the ligne with mat-select and mat-option, but its has the good value but graphically, i don't see my value selected.

```js
public onRowEditInit(user,index) {
    console.log(this.getUsersFormGroup(index).controls['role'].value);
    ///{id:2, name:admin}
    this.getUsersFormGroup(index).controls['role'].setValue(user.role);
    this.clonedUser[user.id] = {...user};
  }
  createUser(p): FormGroup {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      email: [p.email, [Validators.required,Validators.pattern("^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,6}$"),
        Validators.maxLength(50)]],
      password: ['', Validators.maxLength(20)],
      role: [p.role, Validators.required],
    });
  }
```

```html
<mat-form-field class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                            <mat-label>Role</mat-label>
                            <mat-select placeholder="Role" formControlName="role" [(value)]="rowData.role">
                              <mat-option *ngFor="let r of cbxRole" [value]="r">{{r.name}}</mat-option>
                            </mat-select>
                          </mat-form-field>
                          <div *ngIf="getUsersFormGroup(ri).controls['role'].errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                            <div *ngIf="getUsersFormGroup(ri).controls['role'].errors.required">Role obliqgatoire</div>
                          </div>
```

Comment: can i see a instance `cbxRole` array?

Comment: also need to see the `user.role` value ?

Comment: user.role =>{id:2, name:admin}

Comment: cbxRole=>

(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {id: 1, name: "ADMIN"}
1: {id: 2, name: "VENDEUR"}
2: {id: 3, name: "CLIENT"}
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)

Comment: in your cbxRole the name is in all CAPS. but the user.role is all simple letters.it must both  in same case. Or lets say the value must be case sensitive.

Comment: i fix case but the problème is the same

Comment: {id: 2, name: "VENDEUR"}

Comment: Did you need more code